# Define generic datatypes in Z3 C# API

Tags: c#, z3, z3py

I want to declare a generic data structure using C# API (a simple generic wrapper) similar to:

```
public class Wrapper<T> 
{
   public T Element {get; set;}
}

(declare-datatypes (T) ((Wrapper nil (Element T))))
```

1. How can I do that in C#?
2. How can I make an instantiation providing a specific type like:

   (declare-const instance (Wrapper Int))

Answer (score 1):

There are some examples here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/dotnet/Program.cs#L1565-L1734

Comment: I cannot seem to fully understand the example - I can't see where the generic type is used. I've updated the question.

Comment: The API may not allow for parameterization, I'm not sure. Asking directly at z3's github site might get a better response.

Comment: Yeah, I've opened an issue there: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1719. Once they'll respond I'll update this question.